# Codeigniter- how load new page after removing index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeIgniter. I have some links in my index file.
I have removed index.php from url so now url look like

http://localhost/app/Loader/demo_page

This if my Loader code:

```
class Loader extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('center');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function demo_page()
    {
        $this->load->view('demo');
    }
}
```

When I click on this link, I get not found error.

Now what should I do?

I want to remove controller name also from url and want to show pretty url only like domain/app/mydemopage.php.
Please help.

Comment: if you are doing this just for seo-friendly url then use routes.php , paste your whole path in routes.php and define the url which you want.

Comment: Yes, i tried but routing is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need URL Rewrite module for this to work.
How to get this working depends on the web server you use.

For Apache, edit `httpd.conf` and uncomment (remove leading `#`) the following line then restart the webserver.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Add/edit `.htaccess` file in your CodeIgniter root folder and insert this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you get RewriteEngine not allowed here error, make sure the web root folder of CodeIgniter allows `FileInfo` override in your webserver config `httpd.conf`.

`AllowOverride FileInfo`

Comment: I am using apache server, i tried but yet not working, i am getting object not found error

Comment: @RedEye_0 Not working is too generic. You have to find out what went wrong by checking the logs for detailed error messages. Please note that you shouldn't remove the `index.php` file in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your route file using below example. In string I am passing controller and function (method) name. And in $route array I am passing pretty name as I like.

```
#Route file path : CI_project/applications/config/routes.php

$route['default_controller'] = "Dashboard";
$route['contact-us'] = "dashboard/contact_us";
```

But please keep in mind that if you want to make above code work you have to enable rewrite module and give this code in .htaccess.

## .htaccess file code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /prjectName/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
 # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: Pawan Nagar
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```